# Not null field set later in the transaction

Tags: postgresql

Hi I have a situation that
`Table A` has `table_b_id` field,

In my code first record in `Table A` is created, then record in `Table B` with id from `Table A` record,
and in the end update is going into `Table A` record with record from `Table B`.
So typical cyclic ids connections.

Is it possible to not have `table_b_id` field nullable ? 
Like do everything in one transaction.

Comment: you could use a default value for the table_b_id, and when the record gets created on table B you can update that value to the correct id

Comment: You've implemented a 1:1 relation by adding a column to both tables instead of just one. One of the columns is superfluous, remove it.

Comment: @Andomar well I did not want this design, thats why not I am looking for solution

Comment: @Bergi constraint is deferrable but so what ? problem is while adding record into TableA

Comment: Oh you mean you already are doing it one transaction with a deferred constraint, your issue is about having to do the update after the insert?

Comment: What generates the `table_b_id`? Is it a `serial`, i.e. a default value fetched from a sequence?

Comment: no no, issue is with insert to tableA, first operation as table_b_id is NOT NULL a

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the bloating of table A, because it is written twice during your operation:

1. Insert into `table A`
2. Insert into `table B`
3. Update record of `table A`

Due to its MVCC, PostgreSQL doesn't perform a **REAL** update but a `DELETE` + `INSERT`, and your will have a dead tuple into `Table A`.

I had the same configuration on a previous application, I was working with. I was heavily inserted and we had bloat problems, until I reviewd the database model.

Comment: well I dont like this model, but decision about this design is not on me

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use **DEFFERABLE** on `NOT NULL` constraint

> in PostgreSQL, it does not apply to NOT NULL and CHECK constraints

[Link to the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-set-constraints.html)